# What is the best way to stay connected in Europe?

Tags: europe, international-travel, internet, backpacking

What is the best and cheapest way to have data connectivity throughout your euro trip? I have heard about pocket internet devices, European Sim cards, and international roaming cards? which is the best option! and what are the requirements for getting a European sim card?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately, "best" is a subjective term: what my be best for you might not be best for me. Hence why I am closing as opinion-based. Please do not hesitate to use the search function to look for similar questions on the topic, and do know that [roaming will disappear from the EU in June](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations) (with some caveats).